# How to add a svg to work space by click button?

Tags: svg

Maybe this is very simple for you, but not for me...
I want a simple button that which when is pressed add a svg (preference a circle) to the work space.
Something like this https://codepen.io/davecar21/pen/jYQLEO
but I don't want an animation, just a simple svg (preference circle).

```
$('button').click(function() { $('svg animate.anim1').attr("begin", 2); $('svg animate.anim2').attr("begin", 3); })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('draw').addEventListener('click', function(){

document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = 
'<svg height="100" width="100">' + 
  '<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(130,130,130,0.6)">' + 
'</svg>';

});
```

```html
<button id="draw">Draw Circle</button>
<div id="here"></div>
```